# Java 8 , convert hashmap program in Lambda

Tags: java, java-8

We implemented below code in java 7. How to migrate into java 8 with lambda expression code.

```
HashMap<String, String> books = new HashMap<>();
books.put("book1", "java loop scala oracle test");
books.put("book2", "kids children horror movie test");

HashMap<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();

for (String key : books.keySet()) {
    String[] values = books.get(key).split("\\s");
    for (String value : values) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(key);
        if (result.containsKey(value)) {
            result.get(value).addAll(data);
        } else {
            result.put(value, data);
        }
    }
}
for (String key : result.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key " + key + " value " + result.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean using `Stream`s? Lambdas can't be used anywhere you want.

Comment: s.. using stream only

Comment: Did you try anything yourself or do you want the work to be done for you?

Comment: With Guava you can do `Maps.transformValues(str -> Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s")))`

Comment: I hope you're using `result` for more than simply that final print loop, or this is all a grand waste of time.

Comment: Actually i am trying to use stream api to achieve the above program result

Comment: Yeah you said that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with `Stream` if you want like this for example:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> res = books.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.getValue().split("\\s"))
                                .map(y -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(y, x.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene.. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need a Stream for every task; Java 8 also allows to simplify ordinary Collection operations. For some tasks, such a solution might be simpler than a Stream solution:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
books.forEach((key, values) -> {
    for(String value: values.split("\\s"))
        result.computeIfAbsent(value, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(key);
});
```

```
result.forEach((key,value) -> System.out.println("Key " + key + " value " + value));
```

By the way, when you’re using `for` loops, you should question you habit of iterating over the `keySet()` to perform a lookup for every key. There’s `entrySet()` allowing to iterate over both, key and value without the need to perform a lookup. As shown above, the `Map.forEach` may greatly simply the syntax of such an entry iteration, where applicable.